# Custom 403 error in Apache config

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration

I'm trying to set up a config in Apache so that only one IP address has access to the site, but so that a friendly 403 error is shown to other people.

I have the below code, whcih effectivly works, but because of the restricted access to the location of the 403.php file, showing the custom 403 is also forbidden.

The reason for doing this way is because 403.php needs to reference some functions (`get_header()`, `get_footer()`, etc) so I have to have it in this location.

Is anyone able to provide some assistence or advice? Thanks.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName dummy.dynedrewett.com
        ServerAlias dummy
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/intranet/intranet_test
        ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/dummy.dynedrewett.com-error
        CustomLog /var/log/httpd/dummy.dynedrewett.com-access combined
        ErrorDocument 403 /wp-content/themes/dyne_drewnett/403.php
</VirtualHost>

<Directory /var/www/html/intranet/intranet_test/>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from 192.168.1.47
</Directory>
```

Comment: has been a while since I configured apache, but can't you just add a Directory section for /wp-content/themes/dyne_drewnet allowing access to All ?

Comment: That simple! It does pose a few challenges with some required files not being included, but that is very fixable. Thanks for your help.

Comment: stijn, you should repost your comment as answer, so that David can mark this question answered...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a seperate `<Directory>` section for /wp-content/themes/dyne_drewnet allowing access to `All` should fix the access problem.